# how we can use variables, which are described inside the loop, out side the loop in python

Tags: python

Below is my code. Here, I am trying to read the variable gobs(x) from an input file and then I want to use it for other calculations, eg., computing error(x). But, I found, I can read it from input file properly within the loop, but when trying to use it outside the loop, only the first data is getting transferred. For all 100 data, which I read as gobs(x) inside the loop, it is showing the value of last data only, when I am using it outside the loop.

code started below

```
constant = 99

x0=50

z0=5

def gsyn (x):

     return (constant*z0)/(z0**2+(x-x0)**2)

with open ('Grav_H_Cyln_v3_output.txt') as finp:

    lines=finp.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        g=float(line)
        x=line
    def gobs (x):
        return g
    print (gobs(x)) # here, gobs(x) is printing properly   

def error(x):

    return (gsyn(x)-gobs(x))


for i in range (1, 100, 1):

    x=i

print (error(x)) # here, only the first value of gobs(x) is coming

print ('stop')
```

Comment: loops do not create a scope in python, functions do

Comment: You are recreating `gobs` in each iteration..

Comment: It sounds like you want to process data that starts off in a file. As you read the data from the file, you should store it somewhere. Perhaps `gobs` should be a list that you append each `float(line)` to.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very odd solution to what is fundamentally a very simple problem. Make `gobs` a dictionary so you can set or retrieve `gobs[x]` at will.

```
gobs = dict()
with open ('Grav_H_Cyln_v3_output.txt') as finp:
    lines=finp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
         g=float(line)
         gobs[line] = g
         print (gobs[line])
```

Comment: Thank you so much., after making gobs a dictionary, I can see the data outside the loop. But, it is not coming as sub-scripted variable like gobs(1), gobs(2) etc. If I am giving print gobs[line], it is giving error. If i give print gobs, it is printing all 100 values. I need to do operation one by one, that is gsyn(1)-gobs(1), gsyn(2)-gobs(2), like that. How I can do that? Please help.

Comment: Use square brackets around an array or dictionary subscript, i.e. `gsyn(1) - gobs[x]` etc

Comment: for i in range (1, 100, 1):
     line=i
     print (gobs[line])

Comment: KeyError means you tried to print `gobs[x]` for an `x` which isn't in `gobs`. Square brackets everywhere; you cannot meaningfully use a dict as a function.

Comment: ... But really, if you are completely unfamiliar with basic Python syntax, perhaps you should try a tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a vector `gobs[]` **outside** the loop, and filling it up within the loop over `lines`.
That should do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **reassigning** the value of `x` on each iteration of your loop, append `i` to a list that is declared **outside** of the if-block scope.

```
x = []
for i in range (1, 100, 1):

     x.append(i)

print(x)
```